# Check if specific Menu Item exist in the Mouse Right Click Menu

Tags: excel, vba, menu

The following code adds Menu Items to the mouse right click menu successfully.

```
Sub AddMenuItemsToTheMouseRightClickMenu()
Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems.AddMenu Caption:=("FIRST MENU")
Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems.AddMenu Caption:=("SECOND MENU")
Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems.AddMenu Caption:=("THIRD MENU")
End Sub
```

I need a vba code which checks if specific Menu Item exists in the mouse right click menu.

So, the following code needs to be repaired.

```
Sub CheckIfSpecificMenuItemExistInTheMouseRightClickMenu()
    If Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems("SECOND MENU").Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Yes, exist"
    End If
End Sub
```

I did some internet searches but there is no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `COUNT`, try using `INDEX` instead:

```
If Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems("SECOND MENU").Index > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Yes, exist"
End If
```

You will need to add an error handler for when it doesn't exist, however.